# Doctrine2 - Joining Entities without Associations Using ORM QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to generate the query for Joining unassociated Entities using the ORM QueryBuilder as in :

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM User u JOIN Blacklist b WITH u.email = b.email');
```

Comment: Yes, but having the foreign key will make your query orders of magnitude faster if you have a remotely large data set and costs you virtually nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why not...the QueryBuilder just converts down to DQL anyway.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u')
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->join('Blacklist', 'b', 'WITH', 'u.email = b.email')
;
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I will test it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I tested creating this and then doing `echo $qb->getDql();` to make sure it looked the same.  The only difference was that the join became 'INNER JOIN', but 'JOIN' is just an alias for that in Doctrine anyway.

Comment: Hello @user2268997, just checking to see if this ended up working for you.

Comment: Somehow I can't seem to remember, I'll accept your answer until I recheck it.